# Please remove and blacklist the [begin] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

Out of [8 questions currently in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/begin), 5 were created by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71470/peter) as an obvious attempt to circumvent the blacklist, and the other 3 are on questions from people who didn't really understand the tagging system.

I see no reason for this tag to exist.  Even if it were being used legitimately, it's used in so many different contexts to mean so many different things that it's pretty useless for categorization.  The most likely use in the future is exactly what it's being used for now (garbage).

Can this tag be removed from the system and added to the blacklist?

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the tags in the referenced user's questions.  I also cleaned up the tags in the other questions; some of them had both the [begin] and [end] tags.

[begin] is a meta-tag; it [cannot be effectively used on a question as the sole tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: +1 for `[status-completed]`-ing this.

Comment: Thanks.  I kind of didn't want to bump his questions since they were kind of... bad... but at least the tags are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]